# Dictionary.ContainsKey() throws KeyNotFound Exception

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary full of lists. Before I add a new key to the dictionary I check if its already in the dictionary. If so I add the object to the list. If not I create a new object and add it to the dictionary with the key. The problem is that the Dictionary.ContainsKey() function sometimes throws a KeyNotFound Exception which makes no sense to me at all.

I have tried using the Dictionary.TryGetValue() function which had the same problem. I also made sure that the key is not null.

```cs
string key = time.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(key);

if (!synthSong.Track[difficulty].ContainsKey(key))
{
  List<SynthNote> notes = new List<SynthNote>();
  notes.Add(note);
  synthSong.Track[difficulty].Add(key, notes);
}
else
{
  synthSong.Track[difficulty][key].Add(note);
}
```

The weird thing is that the exception only happens for some datasets.

Comment: Are you sure that the call to `ContainsKey` throws the exception? What happens, when the `Track`dictionary does not contain the `difficulty` key?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others, that will throw the exception you get.

Comment: You are of course right. It was not the key key that threw the exception but the difficulty key. I feel very silly now -_-

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The program converts song files from one rythm game to another. For that I read the data from a json file and export it to another json file. To do that I have one class each containing all the relevant information like the difficulty that is used by the json (de)serializer. The error happened when I was in the middle of updating the program to support more difficulties. I had already changed the difficulties on the import side and in the code that maps the information to the export class but not in the export class itself. So the difficulty key I was writing didn't exist in the export class (named synthSong). I wrongly assumed the error was caused by checking the key variable which would have made no sense. I guess this is why "key" isn't the best name for a variable that is going to be used as a key. Also it might be better style not to initiaize the dictionary with all of the difficulty keys but to create them as they come.

Comment: Don't be; it happens to everyone. Anyway, this is not a real answer, so you could do one of the following: edit this answer, pointing out the real error and the fix or delete the question (I advice for editing).

Comment: I knew the first solution was bad but I didn't really know how to explain it better since that would have required to post tons of code. I hope this is better as a solution.